# c++11 Uniform initialization does not work with clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I copied the following example from [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Uniform_initialization):

```
struct BasicStruct {
    int x;
    double y;
};

struct AltStruct {
    AltStruct(int x, double y) : x_{x}, y_{y} {}

private:
    int x_;
    double y_;
};

BasicStruct var1{5, 3.2};
AltStruct var2{2, 4.3};

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

I then tried to compile it with

```
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

but I get this error:

```
test.cpp:17:11: error: non-aggregate type 'AltStruct' cannot be initialized with
      an initializer list
AltStruct var2{2, 4.3};
          ^   ~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

My clang version `clang++ --version` is

```
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.61) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Shouldn't this example work? Maybe clang just isn't fully c++11 compatible yet?

What's going on?

Comment: Yes, this should compile. It conforms to the standard. GCC 4.7 compiles it. Maybe indeed a problem in Clang.

Comment: Apple clang 3.1 is not the same as the LLVM Clang 3.1 release. Apple's version is a bit older, missing some parts that were implemented later.

Comment: Note that any version of any compiler at the current day does not implement all of C++11, and that it doesnt here shouldn't surprise you. What surprises me otoh is the big amount of people that already after a few days after C++11 was issued, were stunned that not all of it has been implemented yet.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: There's actually only one compiler that implements all of C++98, and it's neither GCC nor MSVC...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I am not surprised. For many languages (such as Java), when a feature is advertised, it's in! C and C++ are the odd ones out here, since features are first standardized (and advertised) before being actually implemented (on a large number of compilers).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: For most of those languages, the current implementation is the specification, and there is often not more than this one implementation (and if there is, all other but the leading one are usually behind).

Comment: @PlasmaHH: so ? This is irrelevant to what people get used to :) Most people don't know there is a Standard behind C++, for them the Standard is whatever their compiler does.

Comment: @simon Also, lambda won't work and variadics will work badly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hint is actually here:

```
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.61) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
                                                                   ^~~~~~
```

This means that it is not the 3.1 version proper, but somewhere between 3.0 and 3.1.

The support for uniform initialization was implemented somewhere between those two versions so the version that Apple has probably has either absolutely no support or just partial support.

Comment: Apple has its LLVM/clang version all messed up. I suggest installing clang 3.1 release via MacPorts. Saves me tons of hair pulling.

Comment: @StephenChu: I agree, it would be so much simpler if they at least started from a release of Clang/LLVM instead of taking a snapshot of ToT when they please :(

Answer (score 0):

> error: non-aggregate type 'AltStruct' cannot be initialized with an initializer list

That's definitely wrong, see 8.5.4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list] §3:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, **if T is a class type, constructors are considered**

And since `AltStruct` has a constructor taking `int` and `double`, `AltStruct var2{2, 4.3};` should compile and have the same semantics as `AltStruct var2(2, 4.3);` (direct initialization).